# AWS Corretto sample application source

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

Would anyone now what is the S3Key for corretto.zip sample app? For S3Key property I tried `corretto-newsample-app.zip` and `corretto.zip` but I get a 400 error in Cloud Formation.

```
Unable to download from S3 location (Bucket: elasticbeanstalk-samples-eu-west-1 Key: corretto-newsample-app.zip). Reason: Forbidden: S3Bucket=elasticbeanstalk-samples-eu-west-1, S3Key=corretto-newsample-app.zip (Service: AWSElasticBeanstalk; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination;
```

If I use the PHP sample app from the AWS example `php-newsample-app.zip` it works fine and I can successfully start an EB environment, but I would like to use a Java sample app.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer on the AWS community website.
It's `java-sample-app.zip`